# facebook like chat with the options of adding or removing friends

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook-chat

Any such free script that will enable facebook like chatting for registered users with the options of adding, removing friends, showing online friends etc in a php website?

I found one at: http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/. but the options to show online friends,adding, removing friends  are not there.

Anyone there?

Comment: are you using a CMS?? If yes which one... I've seen plugins exactly like the facebook chat....

Comment: http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/10_chat_widgets.php

Comment: nice list... i remeber one exactly like fb. it was for drupal....

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/drupalchat

Comment: @pixelass, looking for using in  a php site, raw php

Comment: @atornblad , I am looking for a chat script that will enable the users registered in the site to chat with one another. all the scripts ur recommended page listed aim at chatting with yahoo, msn etc users. hope u understand what i am looking for

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed ... I know.. I just wanted to show you the link.. maybe you can work with the code,, I used it once and it worked pretty much like FB...

Comment: Yes. Since you are creating your own authorization system, including your own user database and user administration, you are probably stuck with reinventing the entire wheel on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Freichat](http://evnix.com/drupal2/) is a free script with an active forum